# VS 2008 - Link against older C runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

How can I compile using Visual C++ 2008 and link against an older version of the C runtime (I want version 7 instead of 9)?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you have to do is find the Linker -> Input property page for your project and tell it to specifically ignore msvcrtd.dll / msvcrt.dll and then explicitly link to the version you want (full path).  Not sure what will happen if they have the same name...

Answer (score 3):

VS is only an IDE. You can use it to build with an older toolset, but it requires some tweaking - you need install two side-by-side VS installation (e.g. VS2008 + vs6) and load with different VSARGS. See this excellent [step by step](http://resnikb.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/using-visual-studio-2008-with-visual-c-6-0-compiler/) from Bojan Resnik.

Note that in VS2010 this solution is not applicable - it has a new per project settings->general->"platform toolset". 
If desired, install [this](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/) and manually update project settings->VC++ directories (or manually change the default [settings](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/dc9f28f0-4f56-4da2-8413-2116c10b31a6)).

Comment: Hi, i have installed Daffodil as per your comment, but I am unsure of what to do with the VC++ directories. Could you possibly give me some advice on that please?

Comment: Well, IIRC, after installing that tool you only need to select the toolchain (rather then modifying the VC directories...). See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx under "How to enable native Multi-targeting?".

Answer (score 1):

I think Microsoft specifically says "don't do this."  The thing is, msvcrt.dll is now considered to be part of the OS, not part of any particular app, and not a redistributable.  MS may update it with a Service Pack, and may change behavior significantly, as they did with XP SP2.  Which would break apps!  So... [Don't Do It](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).

Comment: if you build ur application using vs2008 it will rely on msvcr09.dll which exists in winsxs folder not in the windows\system32 folder

Comment: I don't know what question you're answering but certainly it's not the one asked by Jimmy here...