# Which runtime libraries to ship?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I work on C/C++ using Visual Studio 2008. I believe that I am not concerned about which runtime libraries are being used by my code as I have the developer setup. But when the executable is shipped, the runtime libraries being used need to be shipped alongwith. Am I right?

If yes, how can I identify which shared libraries are actually getting used? Or are there any libraries that we can ship without having to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you need to ship a version of the C runtime libraries that matches the version you linked your application against.  If you're compiling with Visual Studio 2008, then you want to use the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en).  As other folks mentioned, you can inspect your application's manifest file to see exactly which version of the C runtime libraries it's linked against.

Before shipping, it's always best to install your product on a clean (i.e., non-developer) virtual machine and run [Microsoft's Dependency Walker utility](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify that your application uses the correct C runtime libraries.

Comment: I got a test machine where Visual Studio is not installed and I have seen from manifest and also the Dependency Walker that there is dependency on Microsoft.VC90.CRT or specifically MSVCP90.dll, MSVCR90.dll.

Comment: Contd..
My app is a Java app running in Tomcat. It uses C++ dlls which are present in apache-tomcat/bin/build/dll. I copied all MSVC*.* dlls alongwith manifest file in this folder and later on in bin folder and then under apache-tomcat folder also. But the dependency error is still being shown when the application runs. Setting up the Path environment variable also didn't help. I was doing all this thinking that if I paste CRT dlls in working directory, dependency should get removed. Can you suggest something?

Comment: You shouldn't copy the files to your application's directory; you should install the appropriate C runtime so that it's available to all applications on that computer.  Use the link that I provided in my answer to install the appropriate runtime libraries.

Answer (score 2):

you need to ship dll files with you.

you can guess most of them and for the rest you can use a program "Dependency Walker" which shows you dependencies of the executable.

Comment: I've heard that the dependency walker doesn't work properly since MS introduced side by side assemblies.

Comment: It's been updated to handle side by side assemblies better.  See the link in my answer.

Comment: I think the keyword here is "better", you still can't rely on getting exact information from it. Better to use the manifest file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about not being able to rely on it for "exact information".  It displays the information contained in the embedded manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the generated [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229%28VS.80%29.aspx) file to see which version of the CRT you need to ship with. It's possible to change which version of the CRT you link to as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730134/how-to-enforce-c-compiler-to-use-specific-crt-version) but it doesn't seem to be recommended.