# Winsock2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, compilation, mingw32, windows-2000

I'm trying to compile [this](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/351/) with mingw32 for Linux.

However, I get the following errors and warnings:

```
# i586-mingw32msvc-gcc ms04-020.c -lws2_32 -o ms04-020.exe
ms04-020.c:43:22: error: Winsock2.h: No such file or directory
ms04-020.c: In function ‘main’:
ms04-020.c:113: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:114:11: warning: unknown escape sequence '\;'
ms04-020.c: In function ‘readwrite’:
ms04-020.c:251: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:259: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:264: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:279: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:285: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:290: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:301: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:307: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:312: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c: In function ‘client_connect’:
ms04-020.c:333: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
ms04-020.c:343: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

How can I fix the error regarding `Winsock2.h`? I did manage to get this to compile using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 which would be an acceptable solution, however [compiling with Visual Studio 2010 or later makes the application incompatible with the Windows 2000 target OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2664607/413180). So even though it builds in this manner, the binary won't execute.

Comment: Is the Windows system header files in a path that is searched by the compiler by default? You might need to use the `-I` (capital i) option to add the path.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't have the `Winsock2.h` file - where can I get it?

Comment: I don't know if there's a MinGW package that contain the WIN32 system libraries and header files, you should look for that. If not there should be plenty of tutorials how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you could guess with its name, `winsock2.h` is directly related to Windows implementation of TCP/IP sockets, and exists only on Windows systems.

It may be hard to have full compatibility of `include` between Windows and Linux. IMHO, you should :

- remove `#include <winsock32.h>` from your source for Linux compilation or better write :

  ```
  #ifdef _WIN32
  #include <Winsock2.h>
  #endif
  ```
- add (eventually in a `#else` section) the missing headers

Currently, `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’` shows that you are lacking a `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Great - the `#else` section was not needed - it compiled by taking out the `#include <Winsock2.h>` line and adding `#include <stdio.h>`.