# Can VS2010 create native executable file working under Windows 2000?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, native

I plan to develop some native C++ project in VS2010. But it is possible my client will require to support Windows 2000. I know VS2008 creates native executable files compatible with Windows 2000. I would like to migrate to VS2010 but i don't know if it is possible to create native executable file compatible with Windows 2000 in VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRT of VS2010 uses kernel32.EncodePointer() function which is missing in Windows 2000.
Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484511/can-i-use-visual-studio-2010s-c-compiler-with-visual-studio-2008s-c-runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You can write applications for Windows 2000 SP4 using Visual Studio 2010, so long as you only target Version 2.0 of the .NET framework.

Anything higher than .NET 2.0 is not guaranteed to run on Windows 2000 SP4.

You can see the system requirements for each framework here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention that i need native application. Now i fixed my question.

Comment: Then you should get the express edition of VS 2010, and try to compile your programme on a Win2000 machine.