# Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 2000

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-2000

Apparently visual studio 2010 built DLLs do not support Windows 2000. Is there a way to build with Windows 2000 support?

If not, I want to down convert my solution to compile in Visual Studio 2008. I have the solution downgraded, but the project files seem to be tricky. I believe they have changed the format quite a bit between versions. How would I go about downgrading the project files?

Comment: I am not sure if W2K has a WinSxS cache, but did you install the redistributables?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484511/can-i-use-visual-studio-2010s-c-compiler-with-visual-studio-2008s-c-runtim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compatibility problem and the workaround is described in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2005279).

There is no down-conversion option to go from a .vcxproj to a .vcproj.  Perhaps the changed filename extension is the strongest hint, but the project file format was changed dramatically in VS2010.  The build plumbing was completely changed to support building with msbuild.exe.  You'll have to recreate the project from scratch in VS2008.

Comment: Agreed: You'll need to make your projects in VS 2008.

Comment: I figured it out, apparently you can still use VS 2010, but with the v90 toolset (VS 2008 tools) if you have VS 2008 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you create your project in VS2008 it may not work.

The root of the problem is .net framework support. Windows 2000 does not support .net 3.0 or above, therefore you will not be able to create all project types.