# Can I use build against the 2008 VS Runtime with VS 2010 and no copy of VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, runtime, python-2.7

It looks like using Visual Studio 2010 it is possible to build against the 2008 runtime, if you have both editions installed: [Can I use Visual Studio 2010's C++ compiler with Visual Studio 2008's C++ Runtime Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484511/can-i-use-visual-studio-2010s-c-compiler-with-visual-studio-2008s-c-runtim)

Is it possible to do this using just the free Windows Platform SDKs and VS 2010?  Just to stress - installing Visual Studio 2008 is *not* an option.

Background: I'd like to build a Python module for Python 2.7.  I have a copy of Visual Studio 2010, but Python 2.7 (specifically the Python(x,y) distribution) is built using 2008.  Rebuilding Python, or rebuilding Python(x,y) is not something I want to get into (there are various other modules I want to use as well).  My module needs to link against vendor-supplied libraries built using VS 2008/2010 (I've been given both sets of libraries).  I don't own a copy of Visual Studio 2008, and I really don't want to have to buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx) says that although you can change the platform toolset in the IDE you still need to have the VS2008 binaries installed.

I know you said installing 2008 was not an option but perhaps you can still find the free versions in an old SDK or even the Express version on the [Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20682).

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks - I hadn't thought of using the Express Edition.  (My problem with installing 2008 was that I believed I would have to buy a license.)

Comment: Installed it after VS 2010 and seems to have no problem - appears in the list of platform toolsets.