# What is the minimum OS for a windows console app made with Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: windows, console, operating-system, requirements, visual-c++-2010

I've created a console application using Visual C++ 2010. What is the earliest version of windows I can run the program on? I know that it can depend on what Windows API functions that you use in the program, so I only use the following functions in my program:

- [GetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetConsoleTextAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Everything else in the program is standard C++. I know that console applications should be able to run on very early versions of Windows, but I do not know how VC++ 2010's compilation affects the minimum operating system requirement. So, would a console application compiled on Windows Vista with Visual C++ 2010 be able to run on, say, Windows 95, ect.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Can I use Visual Studio 2010's C++ compiler with Visual Studio 2008's C++ Runtime Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484511/can-i-use-visual-studio-2010s-c-compiler-with-visual-studio-2008s-c-runtim), VS C++ 2010 runtime depends on features from Windows XP SP2. So, unless you do some workarounds to avoid the C++ 2010 runtime, that is the oldest version you can target.