# Value error trying to install Python for Windows extensions

Tags: python, command-line

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 installed already. I downloaded the zip file [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3083722&group_id=78018&atid=551954) and extracted the contents into my Python27 folder. There's now a subfolder called pywin32-214. (Is the 32 part a problem? I'm on a 64-bit system.) Here's a transcript from the command line:

```
C:\Python27\pywin32-214>setup.py -q install
Building pywin32 2.7.214.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\pywin32-214\setup.py", line 2152, in <module>
    ('', ('pywin32.pth',)),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\pywin32-214\setup.py", line 1251, in run
    install.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\pywin32-214\setup.py", line 596, in run
    build.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python27\pywin32-214\setup.py", line 858, in build_extensions
    self.compiler.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsal
l
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

I don't know what to make of this. Help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a 64 bit Python installation:

Install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition" with the "X64 Compiler and Tools" option enabled.

Alternatively, download pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7.exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/

Comment: It says I don't have a Python27 directory, which I do... do you think maybe it's incompatible with Python 2.7.1?

Comment: Then you likely have a 32 bit Python installation and need to download pywin32-214.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: Tried that... it succeeded in finding the directory but then the install bar stayed completely empty for 10 minutes. I'm going to see if I can find a 64 bit Python installation and then try the original .exe again.

Comment: That is most unusual. You could try alternative installers from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

Comment: faced same issue, installing pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7.exe doesn't work

Answer (score 20):

Another possible reason for this problem to appear is that you have just installed Visual Studio and the command prompt you're using had been hanging around from the time **before** the installation.

This is because MSVC installer sets few environment variables and one of these variables ( VS90COMNTOOLS )has to be set for *vcvarsall.bat* to execute correctly.
But each running program in Windows holds its own local copy of environment variables that gets inherited (copied) from parent process upon child start-up. Thus, after child has started, it does not receive alterations performed on the system-level envvars. And the only way of getting updated environment variables is trough spawning a new instance of a child process with parent that has updated version of envvars.

Comment: Exactly my problem after having installed VC 2008

Comment: Had some trouble installing twisted. Great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

As stated it's trying to use a 32-bit compiler for 64-bit python. I was able to build successfully by:

1. Finding `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64` (depends on your setup)
2. Open a cmd prompt
3. Run `SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%` (depends on setup, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/2362877)
4. Run `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat`
5. Then `pip install <package>`

Comment: this worked for me to run 'pip install usaddress' but without running the 'SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%'  I did however have VS90 pointint to my VS100 install (VS2010 express) haveter I had installed VS2012.

Comment: This will allow you to build, but it will cause problems if someone who doesn't have the VS2012 libraries installed tries to run the extension. It would be better to install VS2008 with the optional 64-bit compiler and use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692402/visual-studio-2008-for-windows-7-64-bit-for-creating-64-bit-binaries

Answer (score 8):

None of these answers worked for me but I found the solution on the issue tracker:

1. Open cmd.
2. cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"
3. Type vcvars32.bat or vcvars64.bat
4. In the same prompt and -without closing: cd back to the Python module you're trying to install.
5. The code should now install.

Source: http://bugs.python.org/issue7511

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. It almost took 2 days to fix this. Thanks @Matthew

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixed on Python 2.7 64-bit (like I am) and too cheap to buy VS2008 Professional, you can also download VS2008 Express and install the Windows 7 SDK to get a compatible 64-bit compiler for free. After that, run the Windows 7 SDK SetEnv.Cmd script and then the setup.py:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd"
> setup.py -q install
```

The SetEnv.Cmd should set up all the environment variables you need for build. When it runs, there should be a message that says "Targeting Windows 7 x64 Debug". You can also use this command to compile in Release mode:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release
> setup.py -q install
```

Answer (score 0):

Python for Windows extensions is only supported on

> 32-bit MS Windows (95/98), 32-bit MS
>   Windows (NT/2000/XP), All 32-bit MS
>   Windows (95/98/NT/2000/XP),  Win2K,
>   WinXP, WinCE

Taken from [the sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). Seems like you may be out of luck!

EDIT: However... reading [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-November/009792.html) seems to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the other answers and a lot more.
Ended up installing python 32-bit, which fixed the issue right away.

If this is an option, it's most likely the easiest fix.