# Visual Studio 2008 for Windows 7 64 bit (for creating 64 bit binaries)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I know the 32 bit visual studio will install on Windows 7 64 bit machine, but I suppose it can only be used to create 32 bit dlls. Is there a separate visual studio installer available to install 64 bit Visual studio that can be used for creating 64 bit dlls?

Edit: Sorry for not visiting my own question for so long. I'm building the solution using devenv command: devenv mysolution.sln /build "RELEASE|WIN64"

It skipped building all projects. So I opened the solution in Visual Studio, and in the build Configuration manager, I set

Active Solution Configuration: Release    Active Solution Platform: win64

But in the Project contexts (check the project configurations to build or deploy):

Configuration: Release                           Platform: Win32 alone is available in this dropdown, not win64.

What do I need to do?

Comment: There is no reason why Visual Studio 2008 could not be used to write 64-bit applications or libraries. It comes with compilers targeting 64-bit platforms (x86_64 and Itanium).

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in noting that Visual Studio (even v2010) is a 32-bit app, and will default to running the 32-bit build environment, which in most cases is good for creating EXEs that work well on both x86 and x64. There are a few [x64 VS components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588.aspx) that you can (and should) choose during the installation.

The build tools are able to [cross-compile for the 3 major platforms, and you can pick which platform you're targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2007/09/08/updated-windows-sdk-visual-c-cross-compilers.aspx). If you want to be sure you're using the x64 compiler, then you want to [run it from the command-line with DEVENV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx).

[Read this article for some "gotchas" on cross-compiling for x64](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/07/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild.aspx).

The build tools are part of the [Windows SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=191420), and the web installer is platform-aware and will install 64-bit capable build environment. (Or if you're downloading the ISO image for installation, be sure to get the x64 one--see the [SDK Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/05/25/released-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-4.aspx).) After installation, you should see icons in the Start Menu group which launch the command prompt with x86, x64 and ia64 options set.

(Lastly, note that there a [known issue only if you have installed the SDK *before* VS 2008 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/06/15/installing-win-7-sdk-rc-and-vs2008-rtm-can-disable-vc-configuration-platform-choices.aspx), but that is fixable following the directions in the KB article.)

Answer (score 4):

VS2008 comes with *three* compilers.  You'll find them back in the vc\bin, vc\bin\x86_amd64 and vc\bin\amd64 subdirectories of the VS install directory.  Respectively a 32-bit compiler to generate x86 code, a 32-bit compiler to generate x64 code and a 64-bit compiler to generate x64 code.  The latter will only work on a 64-bit operating system and is not used by default.  Which you can change with Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories, Platform = x64.

Beware that the 64-bit compilers are *not* installed by default.  You would have had to select the custom setup when you originally installed VS2008.  Re-run setup and reapply SP1 to fix.