# Using easy_install to install Docx

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, pip, easy-install

So this is the culmination of a long list of problems, I'll do my best to summarize quickly.

It started with wanting to use [python docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx), but I could not get easy_install to do install it properly.  I was getting an error similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) so I attempted that solution.  It didn't work.

After reading around, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047542/building-lxml-for-python-2-7-on-windows/5122521#5122521) which told me I need Microsoft Visual Studios, and after a hell of a hunt, I finally found an iso for VS2008 (which I've now installed).  Since then, I've been getting an error similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions).

I've spent most of the afternoon trying to read-up and figure this out, but I'm at a fairly low-level of understanding the actual mechanics of python, so it all just goes over my head.  But here's what I understand (or think I understand) so far:

- Having MSVS2008 is very important
- docx depends on something called lxml, which I downloaded and installed from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

**What I actually need:**  A low level explanation of what all the pieces of this puzzle are doing (easy_install, lxml, MSVS2008, etc), and how I can put them together.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I think I've discovered the source of the issue.  Easy_install attempts to download and install PIL v1.1.7 (the 32-bit version), however, I'm on a 64-bit system and thus need PIL v2.2.1.  I've installed this version of PIL, but easy_install refuses to recognize it and insists on using the 32-bit version.  Is there a way that I can force easy_install to use the version I want?

**LATER EDIT:** I switched over to `pip` instead of easy_install, and the problem persists