# Python - trying to install PyCrypto and MySQL-python in Windows and VisualStudio9

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have visual studio installed and for example I can install lxml but it does not work for PyCrypto and MySQL-python.

I am getting following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsal
l

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']
```

My list of installed packages:

```
D:\>pip list
ipython (2.1.0)
lxml (3.3.5)
mysql-python (1.2.4
pip (1.5.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pywin32 (218)
rsa (3.1.4)
setuptools (5.4.1)
virtualenv (1.11.6)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

What's causing my error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions

Comment: It did not solve my case.