# PIP install errors on Windows 7 x64, Python 3.4.-vcvarsall.bat error, then ValueError:['path'] then many more errors

Tags: python, c++, windows-7-x64

Very excited about Wes and Hadley's feather initiative.

Problem installing on Windows 7 x64 machine.  Specifically, when I

```
pip install feather-format
```

I get the following error and

```
feather
```

is not installed:

```
Added C:\Anaconda3 and C:\Anaconda3\Scripts to PATH.

C:\Anaconda3>pip install feather-format
Collecting feather-format
  Downloading feather-format-0.1.2.tar.gz (99kB)
    100% |################################| 102kB 1.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cython>=0.21 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from feather-f
ormat)
Building wheels for collected packages: feather-format
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for feather-format ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SMD1\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-za6ja3rs\\feather-format\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).
read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\SMD1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpuhmkfhmypip-wheel-
--python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  copying feather\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  copying feather\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  copying feather\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  copying feather\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
  copying feather\tests\test_reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
  copying feather\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
  copying feather\libfeather.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  copying feather\ext.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
  running build_ext
  building 'feather.ext' extension

  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for feather-format
  Running setup.py clean for feather-format
Failed to build feather-format
Installing collected packages: feather-format
  Running setup.py install for feather-format ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SMD1\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-za6ja3rs\\feather-format\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__
).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SMD1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6h_eg1f9-recor
d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Compiling feather/ext.pyx because it changed.
    Cythonizing feather/ext.pyx
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    copying feather\api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    copying feather\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    copying feather\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    copying feather\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
    copying feather\tests\test_reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
    copying feather\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather\tests
    copying feather\libfeather.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    copying feather\ext.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\feather
    running build_ext
    building 'feather.ext' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SMD1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-build-za6ja3rs\\feather-format\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
 '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SMD1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-6h_eg1f9-record\install-record.txt --s
ingle-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SMD1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-za6ja
3rs\feather-format\
You are using pip version 8.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It appears the offender is Microsoft Visual C++ is required(Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).  I looked and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 v.10.0.40219 as well as v.8, 9, 12 are installed.  I also searched for vcvarsall.bat, and it is NOT on my hard drive.

Any help would be great.  I could REALLY use the functionality of feather!

Comment: Look at this please: [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev .  The proposed duplicate solution does not work.  It is also not quite a duplicate.  The error I get and am referencing is clearly different (although probably related) than the problem in referenced answer.  I did try it anyway, and nothing changed, same error even after reinstalling MV C++ 10, and after attempting the accepted solution.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, there are quite a few answers there, all different and of varying degree of reliability and applicability. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26127562/648265 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28617830/648265 are the ones that I tested to work.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev.  I noticed.  Both refer to c++2008 and the problem arising from setup.py not pip.  My question specifically refers to c++ 2010 and pip.   That said, I tried many of the relevant 2010 and pip responses and nothing worked.  I am on x64 Windows 7 and Python 3.4.

Comment: check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers - the 1st in Google on "ms sdk for python 3".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I appreciate the help.  Unfortunately while that looked like it might be on track, and while I now don't get the vcvarsall.bat error, I now get ValueError: ['path'].  I followed all instructions to a tee including removing VS c++10, removing .NET and installing .NET 4, then proceeding through each step with reboots in between each...

Comment: Well, that means the problem stated in _this_ question is indeed solved :^) and this question is indeed a duplicate. For your current error, googling "python module compile ValueError: ['path']" yields http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions as the 2nd result and https://bugs.python.org/issue7511 which it refers to as the 1st.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say that a fix which creates another error is 'solved'.  The first link refers to C++2008, with many possible hack solutions, none of them toward c++2010.  THe second is also C++2008, and from 2011, and even more hacks... But I will relook through it and try to hack this out (I was trying to avoid the hacks).  (I could just delete c:*.*, and the error would not occur anymore either  ;)    )

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not,  very disappointed nothing worked.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I would rather not install more software (this is a machine at work) since I would need approvals and stuff. I am able to use conda to update and install most libraries but this pip install is giving me the vcvarsall.bat error.