# PyOpenGL can't be installed because of "ValueError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyopengl

I'm trying to install PyOpenGL on my cumputer with pip, but it throws the error:

```
ValueError: ['path']
```

It's in msvc9comlier.py, on line 287, in the functiun "query_vcvarsall"

```
rais ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
```

during the installation process and stops. (I use windows.)
What is the problem exactly, and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is there more diagnostic output than just the error itself, e.g., its stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

[Value error trying to install Python for Windows extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions)

this may can help you, please give more information and full output