# can't compile a simple Cython program

Tags: cython

I'm starting a Cython tutorial, available at:
http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html
but, I can not compile the .pyx files:

I wrote a file containing print("Hello World") 
and saved it under hello.pyx

then I made the setup.py file, containing:

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)

then, from the cmd I used the command:
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace[image]

but I'm getting an error - description in the picture
I've used the pyximport module as well, and got the same error.

I'm sure this problem is very eazy to fix, and I would like to know how! :)

I am useing Python 3.4 on windows

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596407/errors-while-building-installing-c-module-for-python-2-7?