# error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status

Tags: python, command-line

I know that the posts aren't missing on this issue, but please bear with me.

I'm trying to install twisted using the command `pip install twisted` on Django 1.9 and Python 3.4, at first when I tried to install it I got a `ValueError: ['path']` error, after browsing on stackoverflow I found out that I need to run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"` and then try the installation again, which gave me this error :

> error: command 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

I don't know from where this error is coming and seems like it only happens on Windows (currently using Windows 10), how can I resolve this issue ? I've already tried most of the answer on this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676728/value-error-trying-to-install-python-for-windows-extensions), without success unfortunately.

Comment: first check if you have `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.exe` on disk and then you can add only folder `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN` to `PATH` and it should work.

Comment: Added it to environment variable PATH, but it didn't change anything, I do have link.exe

Comment: or maybe you find precompiled version on [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) or use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution.

Comment: Do you have this folder on disk ? And always put in question full error message - there can be other usefull information. BTW: did you check in Google what means `exit status 1120` ?