# Is this possible to load the page after the javascript execute using python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is the page I read:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Hello World")
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `Hello World` is added on the HTML page using javascript, when I use the HTML parser, like the `BeautifulSoup` to parse it, it can't parse the `Hello World`, it is possible to me parse the actually result on how the client side really see....? Thanks.

Comment: It might be possible to parse this trivial case but otherwise you need to run all javascript on the page as a real javascript engine to see the result.

Comment: @Ted: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required

Answer (score 17):

I ran into a similar problem when writing web scrapers in python, and I found [Selenium Web Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/) in combination with BeautifulSoup very useful. The code ends up looking something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.yoursite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
...
```

With Selenium WebDriver, there's also functionally for a "wait until a certain DOM element has loaded", which makes the timing with javascript elements easier too.

Answer (score 3):

For a correct representation of what the DOM looks like after javascript manipulation, you'll have to actually execute the javascript. This has to be done by something that has a javascript engine and a DOM (rather than text/markup) representation of the document - typically, a browser.