# Use BeautifulSoup to obtain "View Element" code instead of "View Source" code

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following code to obtain all `<script>...</script>` content from a webpage (see url in code):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import imp

url = "http://racing4everyone.eu/2015/10/25/formula-e-201516formula-e-201516-round01-china-race/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

script = soup.find_all("script")
print script #just to check the output of script
```

However, BeautifulSoup searches within the source code (Ctrl+U in chrome) of the webpage. However, I want to make BeautifulSoup search within the element code (Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome) of the webpage.

I want it to do this because the piece of code I'm really interested in is in the Element code and not in the Source code.

Comment: Do you mean you want to query within the code that is in the script tag?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. I also figured out that I'm going to need to use `json` instead of `BS`, because I want to query in the code that is generated after javascript does its thing. But I still don't know how to do it.

However, I could also just obtain the content of `<script>` and then convert it to python dic using `json.loads`.

Comment: OK. Say you want the first `script` tag, you can use `contents` to get the code and then query it with regex, etc. See what happens if you change your last line to `script[0].contents`

Comment: This still searches within the Source code of the page though, and I want to search in the code that is generated after javascript is done generating page elements.

Comment: OK. One approach helping here might be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047348/is-this-possible-to-load-the-page-after-the-javascript-execute-using-python) and [this tutorial](http://www.kochi-coders.com/2014/05/06/scraping-a-javascript-enabled-web-page-using-beautiful-soup-and-phantomjs/). Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Already tried those, I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to understand is that neither `BeautifulSoup`, nor `urllib2` is a browser. `urllib2` would only get/download you the initial "static" page - it cannot execute JavaScript as a real browser would do. Hence, you will always get the "View Page Source" content.

To solve your problem - fire up a real browser via [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), wait for the page to load, get the `.page_source` and pass it to `BeautifulSoup` to parse:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://racing4everyone.eu/2015/10/25/formula-e-201516formula-e-201516-round01-china-race/")

# wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fluid-width-video-wrapper")))

# get the page source
page_source = driver.page_source

driver.close()

# parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
script = soup.find_all("script")
print(script)
```

This is the general approach, but your case is a little bit different - there is an `iframe` element which contains the video player. If you want to access the `script` elements inside the `iframe`, you would need to switch to it and then get the `.page_source`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://racing4everyone.eu/2015/10/25/formula-e-201516formula-e-201516-round01-china-race/")

# wait for the page to load, switch to iframe
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*=video]")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".controls")))

# get the page source
page_source = driver.page_source

driver.close()

# parse the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
script = soup.find_all("script")
print(script)
```

Comment: Really impressive. Thank you.