# Python/BeautifulSoup with JavaScript source

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

First of all, I am new to Python and BeautifulSoup. So forgive me if I am using the wrong terminology.

I am encountering an issue where when I inspect the element, I was able to find it, but when I go to 'view source', it wasn't there, and it seems that data was pulled via javascript and thus it may be dynamic.

My question is thus, how do I incorporate the data(source/elements/tag) that's 'uploaded' by javascript?

So far, I have the code below. I wasn't able to get the URL for each 'search'

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

rootURL="http://www.homestead.ca"

def HomeStead2(URL):
    thePage = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thePage, "html.parser")
    return soup

soup = HomeStead2(rootURL)

for dropdownlist in soup.find("ul", {"class":"nav navbar-nav primary"}).find('ul').findAll('a'):

"""NOTHING IS WORKING FROM HERE ONWARDS WHEN I TRY TO GET THE HREF"""
    citySoup = HomeStead2(rootURL + dropdownlist.get('href'))
    for btnPreview in citySoup.find("div", {"class":"search extended-search"}).findAll('li'):
        try:
            for ApartmentLink in btnPreview.findAll("div", {"class":"property-container"}):
                print(ApartmentLink)
        except:
            print('skip')
```

[image]

Comment: try selenium -- it reads the javascript and produces the resulting markup

Comment: Does it mean that I don't need to use BeautifulSoup then?

Comment: You need to use Selenium with Python. No need to use BS.

Comment: You need a headless browser - something capable of parsing Javascript. Selenium is one; PhantomJS (a Javascript library) is another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this possible to load the page after the javascript execute using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047348/is-this-possible-to-load-the-page-after-the-javascript-execute-using-python)

Comment: Thanks everyone...I will look into Selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all without selenium, once you visit each apartment url the data is retrieved from an ajax call to an api, all we need is the *city-id*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

root = "http://www.homestead.ca"

data = {'keyword': 'false', 'max_bed': '100', 'geocode': '',
        'min_rate': '0', 'offset': '0', 'max_rate': '4000',
        'show_custom_fields': 'true', 'limit': '50', ''
                                                     'pet_friendly': '', 'city_id': '', 'amenities': '',
        'client_id': '6', 'max_bath': '10',
        'auth_token': 'sswpREkUtyeYjeoahA2i',
        'count': 'false', 'min_bath': '0',
        'order': 'max_rate ASC, min_rate ASC, min_bed ASC, max_bath ASC',
        'city_ids': '', 'region': '',
        'property_types': 'low-rise-apartment,mid-rise-apartment,high-rise-apartment,luxury-apartment,townhouse,house,multi-unit-house,single-family-home,duplex,tripex,semi',
        'min_bed': '-1',
        'show_promotions': 'true'}

get = "http://api.theliftsystem.com/v2/search"
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(root)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    lis = soup.select("ul.child-pages.dropdown-menu li")
    for li in lis:
        city_id = li["data-city-id"]
        data["city_id"] = city_id
        p = s.get(get, params=data)
        print(p.json())
```

You can modify the data to match whatever query you want.

The output will be in json format like:

```
[{'building_header': '', 'office_hours': '', 'name': 'North Park Tower', 'matched_suite_names': ['Bachelor', 'One Bedroom', 'Two Bedroom'], 'matched_beds': ['0', '1', '2'], 'id': 309, 'statistics': {'suites': {'rates': {'average': 950.0, 'max': 1275.0, 'min': 625.0}, 'square_feet': {'average': 0.0, 'max': '0.0', 'min': '0.0'}, 'bedrooms': {'average': '1.0', 'max': 2, 'min': 0}, 'bathrooms': {'average': 1.0, 'max': 1.0, 'min': 1.0}}}, 'geocode': {'longitude': '-80.2605725', 'latitude': '43.1703624', 'distance': None}, 'photo': '1443018148_2.jpg', 'min_availability_date': '', 'address': {'intersection': '', 'country_code': 'CAN', 'province_code': 'ON', 'address': '325 North Park Street', 'postal_code': 'N3R 2X4', 'province': 'Ontario', 'country': 'Canada', 'neighbourhood': '', 'city_id': 332, 'city': 'Brantford'}, 'permalink': 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/325-north-park-street-brantford', 'pet_friendly': True, 'thumbnail_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443018148_2.jpg', 'details': {'location': '', 'suite': '', 'features': '', 'overview': "Located on North Park Street and Memorial Avenue,this quiet building is within walking distance of the following: - Zehrs Plaza, North Park Plaza, Shoppers Drug Mart, Zehrs Grocery Store, Zellers, Pet Store, Party Supply Store, furniture store, variety store, Black's Photography, paint shop and veterinary clinic\xa0  - Restaurants and coffee shops\xa0  - Wayne Gretzky Recreational Arena\xa0  - Medical Clinic,Shoppers Home Health Care Clinic and Pharmacy\xa0  - Catholic Elementary School\xa0  - On bus route "}, 'availability_status_label': 'Available Now', 'availability_status': 1, 'contact': {'email': 'rentals@homestead.ca', 'fax': '(519) 752-6855', 'alt_phone': '', 'name': '', 'phone': '519-752-3596', 'alt_extension': '', 'extension': ''}, 'parking': {'indoor': '', 'additional': '', 'outdoor': ''}, 'property_type': 'High-rise-apartment', 'website': {'url': '', 'title': '', 'description': ''}, 'availability_count': 6, 'client': {'email': 'bcadieux@homestead.ca', 'phone': '613-546-3146', 'id': 6, 'website': 'www.homestead.ca', 'name': 'Homestead Land Holdings'}, 'promotion': {'featured': 0}, 'photo_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443018148_2.jpg'}, {'building_header': '', 'office_hours': '', 'name': 'Westgate Apartments', 'matched_suite_names': ['Bachelor', 'One Bedroom', 'Two Bedroom'], 'matched_beds': ['0', '1', '2'], 'id': 310, 'statistics': {'suites': {'rates': {'average': 975.0, 'max': 1300.0, 'min': 650.0}, 'square_feet': {'average': 0.0, 'max': '0.0', 'min': '0.0'}, 'bedrooms': {'average': '1.0', 'max': 2, 'min': 0}, 'bathrooms': {'average': 1.0, 'max': 1.0, 'min': 1.0}}}, 'geocode': {'longitude': '-80.2482991', 'latitude': '43.1733242', 'distance': None}, 'photo': '1443017488_1.jpg', 'min_availability_date': '', 'address': {'intersection': '', 'country_code': 'CAN', 'province_code': 'ON', 'address': '661 West Street', 'postal_code': 'N3R 6W9', 'province': 'Ontario', 'country': 'Canada', 'neighbourhood': '', 'city_id': 332, 'city': 'Brantford'}, 'permalink': 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/661-west-street-brantford', 'pet_friendly': True, 'thumbnail_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443017488_1.jpg', 'details': {'location': '', 'suite': '', 'features': '', 'overview': 'Located in the North end of Brantford, Westgate Tower is in an area that resembles a city within a city. There are a variety of banks, grocery stores, drug stores, malls, a wide selection of fast food, fine dining restaurants and an after hours medical centre, within waking distance.'}, 'availability_status_label': 'Available Now', 'availability_status': 1, 'contact': {'email': 'rentals@homestead.ca', 'fax': '(519) 751-0379', 'alt_phone': '', 'name': '', 'phone': '519-751-3867', 'alt_extension': '', 'extension': ''}, 'parking': {'indoor': '', 'additional': '', 'outdoor': ''}, 'property_type': 'High-rise-apartment', 'website': {'url': '', 'title': '', 'description': ''}, 'availability_count': 6, 'client': {'email': 'bcadieux@homestead.ca', 'phone': '613-546-3146', 'id': 6, 'website': 'www.homestead.ca', 'name': 'Homestead Land Holdings'}, 'promotion': {'featured': 0}, 'photo_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443017488_1.jpg'}, {'building_header': '', 'office_hours': '', 'name': 'Dornia Manor', 'matched_suite_names': ['One Bedroom', 'Two Bedroom', 'Three Bedroom'], 'matched_beds': ['1', '2', '3'], 'id': 308, 'statistics': {'suites': {'rates': {'average': 1124.5, 'max': 1350.0, 'min': 899.0}, 'square_feet': {'average': 0.0, 'max': '0.0', 'min': '0.0'}, 'bedrooms': {'average': '2.25', 'max': 3, 'min': 1}, 'bathrooms': {'average': 1.375, 'max': 2.0, 'min': 1.0}}}, 'geocode': {'longitude': '-80.2584034', 'latitude': '43.1706331', 'distance': None}, 'photo': '1443017947_1.jpg', 'min_availability_date': '', 'address': {'intersection': '', 'country_code': 'CAN', 'province_code': 'ON', 'address': '321 Fairview Drive', 'postal_code': 'N3R 2X6', 'province': 'Ontario', 'country': 'Canada', 'neighbourhood': '', 'city_id': 332, 'city': 'Brantford'}, 'permalink': 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments/321-fairview-drive-brantford', 'pet_friendly': True, 'thumbnail_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/256/1443017947_1.jpg', 'details': {'location': '', 'suite': '', 'features': '', 'overview': 'Dornia Manor is a quiet, ninety-two unit apartment building located in the North end of Brantford. We offer one, two and three bedroom units and one penthouse suite. The building is located in close proximity to many major services such as banking, shopping, health services, recreational facilities, beauty shops, dry cleaners, schools and churches. There is a bus stop at the front door and highway 403 is within minutes.'}, 'availability_status_label': 'Available Now', 'availability_status': 1, 'contact': {'email': 'rentals@homestead.ca', 'fax': '(519) 752-6855', 'alt_phone': '', 'name': '', 'phone': '519-752-3596', 'alt_extension': '', 'extension': ''}, 'parking': {'indoor': '', 'additional': '', 'outdoor': ''}, 'property_type': 'High-rise-apartment', 'website': {'url': '', 'title': '', 'description': ''}, 'availability_count': 8, 'client': {'email': 'bcadieux@homestead.ca', 'phone': '613-546-3146', 'id': 6, 'website': 'www.homestead.ca', 'name': 'Homestead Land Holdings'}, 'promotion': {'featured': 0}, 'photo_path': 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/lws_lift/homestead/images/gallery/full/1443017947_1.jpg'}]
```