# How to get website script output on python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to write a web scraper in python but I have an issue, the contents of the site are not coded into the html, it seems like they are coming from a different source and I want to know if there's any python library that can fetch the contents for me or if there is such tool in any other language I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Could you show us an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See: [Is this possible to load the page after the javascript execute using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047348/is-this-possible-to-load-the-page-after-the-javascript-execute-using-python)

You'll have to execute the JS and whatever else it is that generates the HTML you want. You can do this in a lot of ways, but the answer I linked above suggests using [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).