# how can i only scrape </div> class ("shopee-category-list__body") from python

Tags: python

im doing a freelancing job, so please tell me how to get only  class from shopee website.....

```
urlpage=urlopen("https://shopee.co.id/fedorafashion page=0&shopCollection=13201396").read()

bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage, "lxml")

results=bswebpage.findAll("div",{'class':"shopee-category-list__body"}
```

Comment: what is happening with your current code versus what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Is the class you want part of the HTML page you download? If it's not (meaning it's later generated by javascript), you should check out this question: [Is this possible to load the page after the javascript execute using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047348/is-this-possible-to-load-the-page-after-the-javascript-execute-using-python)