# Accessing Tables Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States"
source = requests.get(url_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
my_table = soup.find("table", class_ = "wikitable sortable plainrowheaders jquery-tablesorter")
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States"
source = requests.get(url_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
my_table = soup.find("table", class_ = "wikitable sortable plainrowheaders")
```

I was wondering whether anybody knows why the first block of code gives me a none object, but the second block of code returns what I want. Is it something to do with hyphenated class names? Thanks in advance:)!

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047348/is-this-possible-to-load-the-page-after-the-javascript-execute-using-python

Comment: Both examples will not produce a successful result, there is a typo in your code, so you should edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No table in the HTML source (do a view source) has the class `jquery-tablesorter` and thus the first `find()` does not return any hits. Remember that BeautifulSoup does not run client side javascript the way Selenium does and thus classes like `jquery-tablesorter` that are applied by javascript libraries (or any other javascript functionality) will not be present to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: But when I went to inspect the wikipedia page, I copied and pasted the class of the table exactly as "<table class="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders jquery-tablesorter"?

Comment: "inspect" is a live version of the page and would have javascript processing. Try again but using "view source"

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much. Do you know if there is a way to match the HTML source code lines to the parts of the website they correspond to with view source like you can do with inspect?

Comment: alas, no. I have always assumed the chrome view-source to just be the exact text returned "as-is" from the server.