# Headless browser for Python with multithreading, javascript, and Windows support

Tags: python, browser, selenium, mechanize, headless

I've tried the following with no avail

- Mechanize/Twill. No Javascript support
- Selenium. Not headless
- Ghost. No Windows support

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: There's also [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (not really Python-related) and [Spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner).

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required

Comment: You should be able to run Selenium headless, what did you try?

Comment: Using Linux with Xfvb installed you can use selenium webdriver inside a virtual frame buffer. Essentially headless. But I know of nothing similar for windows.

Comment: I'm surprised Ghost doesn't work on Windows. What's the stumbling block?

Comment: Ghost also requires Xfvb, which requires linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success using [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) by having Python generate the Javascript for Phantom to execute. It now also has an interactive REPL, so you should be able to use Python to drive the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

[Spynner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner) is based on PyQt and claims to support all of Webkit's functionality.

Comment: Spynner unfortunately requires X11, and while there are workarounds, the workarounds just add a layer of complexity.