# cannot search the tags from python but can view it at chrome

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

cannot search the following tags inside this URL

```
class="iw_component" id="c1417094965155"
```

i can view it from my desktop chrome browser, but cannot read it when execute the following python script

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display=Display(visible=0,size=(800,800))
display.start()

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')
time.sleep(5)
title=driver.page_source
print title
driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Comment: The page you're trying to load dynamically generates most of its content (including the element you want to find) with JavaScript, so you basically need to emulate browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup not grabbing dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866426/beautifulsoup-not-grabbing-dynamic-content)

Comment: code changed, but still not work, thanks !

Comment: You should leave the code in. Otherwise there's no context for the question.

Comment: sorry, for this accident ! I quote it back for contribution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class name to locate elements using [`find_elements_by_class_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("iw_component")
for div in divs:  # use a descriptive variable name
    html_id = div.get_attribute("id")
    ...
```

---

Also, instead of `time.sleep(5)` to simulate/delay python waiting until all the elements are loaded, [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) can be used to wait for specific elements:

> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
>
> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
> driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
> try:
>     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
>         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
>     )
> finally:
>     driver.quit()
> ```

For you, the part for the locator strategy would be:

```
presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "iw_component"))
```

Comment: it seem not work, but anyway, thanks ! i'm using python 2.7