# Why isn't the html code inside div is being parsed?

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[The html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QE0A.png)

In this image there is html code inside the **div id="root"**

Here is the code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.daraz.com.bd/catalog/?spm=a2a0e.home.search.3.73524591owXnnM&q=mobile' 
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find("div", id="root")
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

Why isn't the html code inside div is being parsed?

Answer (score 0):

The content inside of `<div id="root"></div>` is likely loaded dynamically. You can check on your own if you visit the page with disabled JavaScript.
With your approach, BeatifulSoup doesn't parse the content which was added dynamically (through JavaScript).

More details here => [BeautifulSoup not grabbing dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866426/beautifulsoup-not-grabbing-dynamic-content)

I would recommend using a headless browser in your case to be able to fetch dynamic content which was generated with JavaScript. (headless browser is able to execute JavaScript so it makes dynamic content accessible for parsing)