# BeautifulSoup gives None When using find_all()

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib
import csv,datetime,re

url_ = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/ca/toronto/CYTZ/date/2016-6-25"
mypage = requests.get(url_).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(mypage,'html.parser')
soup.find_all('tr')
```

I was trying to fetch the weather data from wunderground. BeautifulSoup has fetched the source code but I don't know why when I use soup.find_all('tr') it keeps on giving me [] ('None'). Anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Most common scenario would be that page does not contain tag named 'tr'. can you find the tag in page source?

Comment: yes i can, it is inside the 'table'

Answer (score 0):

The table data (most probably) gets populated by javascript. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866426/beautifulsoup-not-grabbing-dynamic-content) question.