# Scraping booking.com with JS part

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

i'm trying to access the data inside the **"hp_location_block__container "** container, but at the moment, even with using PhantomJS, I don't get anything back:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/tz/zuri-zanzibar.html"
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    
    soup.findAll("div", {"class": "hp_location_block__container "})
```

I get:

```
Out[1]: []
```

Comment: Most probably what you are trying to parse is dynamic content. does your html file has a div conatining that class name?

Comment: when i inspect the webpage using google chrome, there should be this class yes

Comment: Your browser has javascript enabled. BeautifulSoup can only parse if the content is in html=driver.page_source. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866426/beautifulsoup-not-grabbing-dynamic-content

Comment: i thought phantomJS was supposed to do the job? doesn't seem to work...