# Python - Load a webpage in hidden

Tags: python

I want to load a webpage in python and do something

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://google.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
//do something
```

But I don't want the browser has been showed on my screen, I want to hide it so that I can do some other stuff,
please give me some advices,
thanks

Comment: You need a headless browser : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required . Also look at PhantomJS (it isn't python)

Comment: You'll probably have to create a custom version of the `webbrowser` module based on the code in `Lib/webbrowser.py` -- or read it and try to figure-out a hack that does what you want. It's very likely to be OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, autoraise is working. 
Example:

```
    import webbrowser

    webbrowser.open('www.yoursite.com', autoraise=False)
```