# Python Scraper Unable to scrape img src

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrape, cloudflare

I'm unable to scrape images from the website www.kissmanga.com . I'm using Python3 and the Requests and Beautifulsoup libraries. The scraped image tags give blank "src".

SRC:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()

url = "http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Bleach/Bleach-634--Friend-004?id=235206"

response = requests.get(url)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

divImage = soup2.find('div',{"id": "divImage"})

for img in divImage.findAll('img'):
     print(img)

response.close()
```

I think image scraping is prevented because I believe the website uses cloudflare. Upon this assumption, I also tried using the "cfscrape" library to scrape the content.

Comment: I recently noticed that the images are loaded via javascript. so I just parsed the javascript that contained the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for `JavaScript` to inject the `html` code for images.

Multiple tools are capable of doing this, here are some of them:

- [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) ([Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver))
- [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)

I was able to get it working with Selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# it takes forever to load the page, therefore we are setting a threshold
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)

try:
    driver.get("http://kissmanga.com/Manga/Bleach/Bleach-634--Friend-004?id=235206")
except TimeoutException:
    # never ignore exceptions silently in real world code
    pass

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
divImage = soup2.find('div', {"id": "divImage"})

# close the browser 
driver.close()

for img in divImage.findAll('img'):
    print img.get('src')
```

Refer to [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests) if you also want to download these images.

Comment: is there a way to do this without opening the browser ? BTW your solution works well. Thanks you.

Comment: well, I am not sure, maybe with a custom user-agent as mentioned by @Kupiakos;
if the only problem with the selenium solution is that it actually opens a browser window, you can use a headless browser like `PhantomJS`

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a [custom user-agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)?
It's typically considered unethical to do so, but so is scraping manga.