# How to Python requests to follow URL like my browser

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I've noticed that the requests library for Python does not follow certain URL redirects like my browser.

For example, when I do:

```
response = requests.get('http://www.bbmt.org/', verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
```

The final URL is https://secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com/action/consumeSsoCookie?redirectUri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbmt.org%2Faction%2FconsumeSharedSessionAction%3FMAID%3DJ3%252BqsjOKzWZhWAeF2bXl%252FA%253D%253D%26JSESSIONID%3DaaaorUqRLHgAe4WCenKv%26SERVER%3DWZ6myaEXBLEt1UgI9cIkvA%253D%253D%26ORIGIN%3D470200154%26RD%3DRD&acw=&utt=

However, in my browser, I am eventually redirected back to http://www.bbmt.org/.

Is there a way to have requests behave like my browser in these scenarios?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The redirect inside the `https://secure.jbs.elsevierhealth.com` is a javascript redirect.
You can see it inside the source-code:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.bbmt.org/action/consumeSharedSessionAction?SERVER=WZ6myaEXBLHj3ZzqSv9HPw%3D%3D&MAID=IBS8Eq6B1iRWhf2ywTW5pg%3D%3D&JSESSIONID=aaa8eY-zM394XcPptT_Kv&ORIGIN=670572791&RD=RD";
```

You will need to run javascript in order to do this redirect (and this is something requests do not do).

If you need a solution for this specific redirect, you can parse the content of the response (in python) and take that specific `URL` and use it to create a new request.

If you need a general solution - you will need to use a headless browser to do that. You can find [more information in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required).