# How to put XPath into optional mode

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This XPath may available sometime or sometime not.

If reject is true then I am using if statement:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time

import bs4
import requests
url="abc"

options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\driver\geckodriver.exe",options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

reject = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/a[1]/div[3]/label")
if reject:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/a[1]/div[1]/span/i").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/a[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]").click()
    time.sleep(5)

# Above code blocking to run below code (if reject is None).

neighbourhood= Select(driver.find_element_by_name("Locality"))
neighbourhood.select_by_value("5001641")
```

**But the problem is if this reject variable XPath doesn't exist so it's showing error & blocking below code.**

how to make this reject variable optional if XPath available then work if not then leave it & run below code.

Comment: you can implement exception handling. This will easily handle this problem.

Comment: Since you cant share the URL it is hard to understand what is going on. I believe the page is doing AJAX (XHR)  and the DOM is updated with the new data coming from the server. Try to look for XHR calls. In Chrome do: F12 -> Network - XHR. Refresh the page and see if the data you are looking for is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the exception. Something like following:

```
...
try:
    reject = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/a[1]/div[3]/label")
except:
    print("No element found")

if reject:
...
```

If you need this more often you could create a utility method for that.

```
def elementVisible(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath);
        return true;
    except:
        return false;
```

Comment: was typing this out but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

**try-except** block will do the trick.

```
try:
  reject = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/a[1]/div[3]/label")
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```

Whenever the xpath is not found, the print statement is executed, and further code gets executed without an error like before.