# Saving a "Save as" redirect from a url in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, zip

**What I am trying to do...**

I am trying to automate a download of a zip file from a URL that does not redirect the URL, but instead opens up a "Save as" prompt the moment you open the URL.

**What I have tried...**

"Urllib request", "Wget", and "Requests" libraries are all giving me a 1KB file which in a text editor reads "Invalid request". This could make sense as the Website URL I am inputting is blank by default, and I don't believe its redirecting the URL to anywhere as I had "allow_redirects=True" using the "Requests" Library. I believe this link is using JavaScript to redirect to the "Save as" and when I click it and head to downloads (In Chrome) and see that there is a download link for this file. This download link appears to always work but I am unsure how to grab it with Python.

**Leads...**

I have found [a lead in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025082/headless-browser-for-python-javascript-support-required) about using the library "Spynner", but I am not sure HOW and WHY that would solve my problem.

**I am using Python 3.8.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [web scraping tool](https://www.scraperapi.com/blog/the-10-best-web-scraping-tools/). They usually have headless browsers and everything you need to "bot like" human behaviour. I would recommend Selenium because you can use it from python directly; here is an example: [File managing Selenium](http://allselenium.info/file-downloads-python-selenium-webdriver/).

Be careful, web scraping is not completely legal so you should have authorization to use it on any web service. Proceed with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Like Juan said, I just needed to use a web scraping tool. After learning selenium I was able to bypass the save as requirement.