# How do I point easy_install to vcvarsall.bat?

Tags: python, distutils, easy-install, visual-studio-2010

I already have MSVC++ 2010 Express installed, and my vcvarsall.bat file is at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC`, which is in my system PATH.  When I run `easy_install`, it can't find vcvarsall.bat.

Is there something I need to set in my distutils.cfg file to point it to my MSVC++ installation?

```
G:\>easy_install hg-git
install_dir C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\
Searching for hg-git
Best match: hg-git 0.2.6
Processing hg_git-0.2.6-py2.6.egg
hg-git 0.2.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\python26\lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.2.6-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for hg-git
Searching for dulwich>=0.6.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/dulwich/
Reading http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich
Reading http://launchpad.net/dulwich
Best match: dulwich 0.7.1
Downloading http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/dulwich-0.7.1.tar.gz
Processing dulwich-0.7.1.tar.gz
Running dulwich-0.7.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\mlin\locals~1
\temp\easy_install-fhraep\dulwich-0.7.1\egg-dist-tmp-qozily
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Also note that switching to the mingw32 compiler [doesn't work for all extensions](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-April/573869.html).

Comment: @martineau Microsoft has released a compiler package for Python 2.7 – for more information see my comment to my answer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> I'd still like to know where to set that reference to vsvarsall.bat...

Well, as martineau wrote you have to have either Visual Studio 2008 or Visual C++ Express installed. Having said that I understand you would like to know where Python looks for this batch file. You can see this by looking at [`definition`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py#l219) of `find_vcvarsall` function in distutils/msvc9compiler.py standard module. Python checks in turn if any of folders saved in the registry under keys

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir`

(for 64bit Windows) or

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VCExpress\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir`

(for 32bit Windows) exists and if so it treats such folder as the one containing `vcvarsall.bat` file. If none of these folders exists Python checks if there's environment variable `VS90COMNTOOLS`. If this variable exits Python treats folder two levels above value of this variable as the folder containing `vcvarsall.bat` file.

See also my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122521/95735) answer which explains why you can't use MSVC++ 2010 to build extensions for Python 2.6

EDIT:
The VC++ 2008 files are now packaged in an installer from MS which can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). Once installed vcvarsall.bat will be in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0`

Comment: Too bad Python doesn't come bundled with gcc. Downloading a 3.3GB VS 2008 iso just to be able to use setuptools on 64 bit Windows with 64 bit Python is kind of absurd.

Comment: @tponthieux That's why [installation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5442340/95735) from binary packages on Windows is so handy.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost True. But many of the packages up on pypi don't have precompiled binary installers, and so installing from source is the only option.

Comment: you can use the mingw compiler with many python modules, just set [build] compiler=mingw in your distutils.cfg (though this often won't work since msvc is the "official" windows compiler for cpython)

Comment: You can install the 64 bit compiler with the W7 SDK and then copy a bat to the "expected location". http://stackoverflow.com/a/19915585/905908

Comment: Since MSVC++ 2008 Express is not longer available, they should update the Windows build to [MSVC++ 2010 Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads) which can still be obtained -- although doing so would have a ripple effect...

Comment: MSVC++ 2008 Express is not available from Microsoft, but it seems you can download an "unofficial" but legal copy from softonic at http://microsoft-visual-cpp-2008-express.softonic.com. You can then add 'c:/Program files/Microsoft Visual Studio 0.0/VC' to your PATH (PIP on a VIRTUALENV could find the C++ compiler for a Python2.7 with that configuration)

Comment: MSVC++ 2008 Express is still available for MSDN subscribers. Here are some SHA1 checksums if you want to verify the validity of ISOs downloaded from somewhere else: en_visual_studio_2008_express_x86_dvd_x13-97868.iso (76c6d28274a67741da720744026ea991a70867d1), en_visual_studio_2008_express_with_service_pack_1_x86_dvd_x15-04728.iso (937bd4a1b299505f286e371b3a5212b9098c38f2)

Comment: @tponthieux "Microsoft has released a compiler package for Python 2.7 to make it easier for people to build and distribute their C extension modules on Windows. The Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (a.k.a. VC9) is available from: http://aka.ms/vcpython27" "It's free (VC Express 2008 is behind a pay wall these days)
It's small (85MB download, 300mb on installed)
It's a per-user install with no reboot required" - Steve Dower. See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-September/024885.html for announcement.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Since the Microsoft compiler package is installed on a per-user basis, distutils does not find it. (At least on my machine.) Do I need to manually set the registry keys? Even when setting these keys, it complains about missing header files, e.g. `stdint.h`, when I try to compile an extension. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @martineau Reporting news here, 2010 is not available anymore (officially) at the time of writing. You can find the installer googling a bit but I'm wondering whether those are safe or not. Otherwise are we forced to purchase VS2010 to compile Python 3.x extensions on Windows?

Comment: @lordscales91: I'm not sure. Maybe you could use the link in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3061839/355230) to download it from `download.microsoft.com`.

Comment: what is your python version? I updated to 2.7.12, and problem solved....

Comment: I see nothing in [release notes](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/) of Python 2.7.12 which would suggest something was changed in this regard. `find_vcvarsall` function is patched by setuptools but I don't see anything relevant in [changelog](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/CHANGES.rst) of setuptools neither.

Answer (score 0):

Met same problem on python 3.9.12 (anaconda),I install Visual C++ for Python at
***C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0***

and find the msvc9compiler.py at

**C:\Users\UserName\anaconda3\Lib\distutils**
showed
**VS_BASE = r"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio%0.1f"**

how to point  the vcvarsall.bat  to python ?

(I added the system PATH but not working at all.)
**C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0**

May you please point out how to add registry for the value?
I did't find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir
in my PC.