# Root cause of 'Unable to find vcvarsall.bat' when installing modules in Python (windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip

Before, I was able to install (using pip) any module in my Python installation on Windows 7. But, some days ago something has happened/changed because when I try to install anything using pip, the following error shows up:

```
Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I am trying to find the root cause of the error. Some days ago I installed Flask and Numpy/Matplotlib (exe installations) and I don't know if they can cause this issue on windows, i.e remove that bat file or change some PATH.

I have searched the web and stackoverflow about the error, and they say you have to install mingw32 or VS express 2008. But this is not really a solution, since a week ago everything was fine on my Python without having installed any of those. Do you have other solutions, so I can still use PIP?

Regards

Comment: A week ago when everything was fine were you trying to install the same module(s)? Some modules require one of the two C compilers you mentioned, while others that are pure Python do not. Also, some modules using C are available pre=built for you so you don't need a compiler for them -- but these usually are supplied as .exe or .msi installers. Don't know how those fit into the pip world.

Comment: well I tried to pip install pyhn today and the same error appears, and I think it's pure Python.

Comment: Ok I was able to install gmail==0.3.1; maybe it's package-related

Comment: Related: [How do I point easy_install to vcvarsall.bat?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6551724/95735). There you'll find answer to your question.

Comment: `pyhn` might be pure Python, but require something that isn't.

Comment: good question...  I occasionally run into this error as well and it's frustrating to fix...