# error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat to compile python modules with Visual Studio 2008 installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I', trying to compile a Python modules on Windows 7 ( Python 3.3 ) and getting the error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat which i read around is related to not having Visual Studio 2008 installed. Bu i have visual studio 2008 installed AND it's in the path, any ideas?

EDIT - i also checked [How do I point easy_install to vcvarsall.bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551724/how-do-i-point-easy-install-to-vcvarsall-bat) but no effects, i tried setting the variable but it's ignored.

EDIT 2 - I've found out by looking at the core that it's now looking for VS100COMNTOOLS instead of VS90COMNTOOLS is the VS studio version different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.3 on Windows is [built with VS2010](http://blog.python.org/2012/05/recent-windows-changes-in-python-33.html), which doesn't match your VS2008. Previous versions of Python did indeed use VS2008.

You'll need to get hold of VS2010.