# Error compiling when installing with pip

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, pip

I'm having issues when installing packages with pip. I'm running python 3.3 in Pyzo (pre-packaged with numpy, scipy etc) on Windows 8.1 64bit. When i try to install packages with pip that needs compile some c, it fails.

At first I got the error "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat". I looked that up and it seemed like it tried to find the compiler that had been used to build the version of python that I'm running.
[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)
[pip install gives error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830942/pip-install-gives-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) 
[Unable to find VCVarsall.bat using Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689652/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-using-python-2-7) 
[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat to compile python modules with Visual Studio 2008 installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953296/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-to-compile-python-modules-with-visual-studio)

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 for my ordinary .Net stuff but apparently python 3.3 is compiled with Visual Studio 2010. So, i installed Visual C++ 2010 express, but it still gave the same error.

I managed to find the source that is used to look for the vcvarsall (msvc9compiler.py in Lib/distutils). So i started poking around in the source and saw that the version it looked for was 9.0 (i.e Visual 2008). So I downloaded 2008 C++ Express and tried it again. This time it found the vcvarsall.bat but instead I got a different error "ValueError: ['path']"
The method that is throwing the error is the following.(The prints are added by me for debugging)

```
def query_vcvarsall(version, arch="x86"):
"""Launch vcvarsall.bat and read the settings from its environment
"""
vcvarsall = find_vcvarsall(version)
print(version)
print(arch)
print(vcvarsall)
interesting = set(("include", "lib", "libpath", "path"))
result = {}

if vcvarsall is None:
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
log.debug("Calling 'vcvarsall.bat %s' (version=%s)", arch, version)
popen = subprocess.Popen('"%s" %s & set' % (vcvarsall, arch),
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    stdout, stderr = popen.communicate()
    if popen.wait() != 0:
        raise DistutilsPlatformError(stderr.decode("mbcs"))

    stdout = stdout.decode("mbcs")
    for line in stdout.split("\n"):
        print(line)
        line = Reg.convert_mbcs(line)
        if '=' not in line:
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        key = key.lower()
        if key in interesting:
            if value.endswith(os.pathsep):
                value = value[:-1]
            result[key] = removeDuplicates(value)

finally:
    popen.stdout.close()
    popen.stderr.close()

if len(result) != len(interesting):
    print(str(result)+"::: "+str(interesting))
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

return result
```

So basically, what is happening is that it checks through my environment variables and looks for the entries in interesting ("include", "lib", "libpath", "path")
Now, the only one of those that I have is "path", so the final if-statement throws the ValueError. 
So, what I'm wondering is what are the others, why don't I have them, why is it looking for them and how can I fix it?

Grateful for all answers.

Regards 
Fredrik

Comment: What does it print for arch?

Comment: Hi, it prints 'amd64'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Visual C++ Express 2010 doesn't include 64-bit compiler. See [How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express).

Comment: Do we need to have Visual Studio to install packages in python? why pip does not use precompiled binaries like R?

Comment: @MajidEinian Pip is a source distribution. I guess that's because of the huge amount of platforms supported, so it's just unfeasible for the author to precompile.

Comment: @Fred_F, did this solution work for you? It didn't seem to help me.

Comment: @clg4 Did you use 64-bit command prompt? You can also see if Microsoft [Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) works for you, if you don't need Python 3.

Comment: @jwalker yes.  the command prompt defaults to 64 bit in windows 7.  Thanks for trying