# how to complie numpy to install on 64 bits platform?

Tags: python, numpy, mingw-w64

My system is :win7 64 ultimate +python34(64)+intel 64 chip.
I have installed mingw64  ,please see:

```
C:\Users\pengsir>d:\mingw\bin\gcc -v
Reading specs from d:/mingw/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/specs
COLLECT_GCC=d:\mingw\bin\gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/lto-wra
pper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=/opt/windows_64 --with-sysroot=
/opt/windows_64 --libdir=/opt/windows_64/lib64 --mandir=/opt/windows_64/man --in
fodir=/opt/windows_64/info --enable-shared --disable-bootstrap --disable-multili
b --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-checking=release --wi
th-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib64/python2.7/site-packages --disable-libunw
ind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --verbose --e
nable-java-home --with-java-home=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-d
ir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jvm-ex
ports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar='/home/adrien/projects/win-bu
ilds-1.4/slackware64-current/d/gcc/antlr-*.jar' --disable-java-awt --disable-gtk
test --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w6
4-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

when i install with the command:

```
d:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe  install numpy
(other message ommitted)


error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

How to compile the numpy to install on the python34?
I don't want to install vs2013 ,i like free software,no money to pay for vs2013 ,please teach me to  complie numpy to install on 64 bits platform  mingw64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some requirement that you build numpy from source? I have always just installed it (and every other Python package that's troublesome on Windows) from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Binaries Page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), which has always worked perfectly for me.

Comment: my cpu is intel 64 not amd64, how can i install amd64 for python packages?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Your actual CPU architecture is completely irrelevant here. The "amd" in the name is just a convention, [probably due to the fact that AMD was the first company to release a (x86-) 64-bit CPU](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53415). The "amd64" binaries are for use with 64-bit Python, whereas "win32" binaries are for 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://shop.wickeddevice.com/2013/12/11/windows-7-python-virtualenv-and-the-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-error/:

1. For Python 3.4, download Visual C++  2010 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.
2. Install it.
3. Open Windows explorer (the file browser) and search for the location of ‘vcvarsall.bat’ and cut it to your clipboard.
   run `regedit` from the Windows start key. You will need admin privilges.
   Add a registry entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir` (64 bit Windows) or
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC\ProductDir` (32 bit)
   (If these don't work, try replacing `VisualStudio` with `VCExpress`
   as described in [How do I point easy_install to vcvarsall.bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551724/how-do-i-point-easy-install-to-vcvarsall-bat/8705722#8705722)
4. Restart `cmd` and try again.

Comment: I don't want to install vs2013 ,i like free software,no money to pay for vs2013 ,please teach me to  complie numpy to install on 64 bits platform  mingw64.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Read the answer again: nowhere does it mention installing Visual Studio. You *need* the **Visual C++ distributable**, which is a library that includes vcvarsall, in order to build any Python libraries that require it. (That said, Hotchips, I think the appropriate registry key here is under `\Microsoft\VCExpress\` rather than `\VisualStudio\`).

Comment: is Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) ,or Visual C++ distributable ,for the first one, ,i have download it,and install it from  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632 .