# Having trouble getting Python to recognize location of vcvarsall.bat

Tags: c++, python-2.7, batch-file, 64-bit, windows-8.1

I was trying to install [RandomWords](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RandomWords/0.1.5) which requires [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson), at some point in the installation I received the following notification: "**error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**" I searched here, on stackoverflow, and came across some answers as the to root of this problem. In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705722, near the end, the OP pointed out that Microsoft had released a C++ compiler package for Python 2.7 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

I installed this package but still haven't had any success in installing ujson. So far I've tried the following:

- Adding the location of vcvarsall.bat to the path environment variable
- Manually tried loading the VC++ compiler's environment into the session by executing vcvars64.bat (aI've tried vcvars32.bat as well) as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045219
- I've also tried installing the compilers found in "Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1" found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138

Not sure where to go from here, any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference here's some relevant specs:

- Windows 8.1 (64-bit)
- Python 2.7 (64-bit)
- I've been trying to install said package using pip from the command prompt (*e.g.* '> pip install ujson')
- I've uninstalled all the C++ compiler packages I've tried except this one: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266
- Really don't feel like installing mingw, but I'll try it if it seems like it's the only solution.

**-UPDATE-**

I ended up modifying "msvc9compiler.py" and manually setting the location of vcvarsall.bat by setting the value of the vcvarsall variable to the location of that batch file. Everything compiled fine but this is not a recommended solution. I'm pretty sure the compiler version I have matches the one python 2.7 uses, but as mentioned in an answer, in another question on this topic, if these don't match it can cause problems since "the compilers will probably have incompatible C runtime libraries."

Comment: Try to install Visual Studio 2008 Express

Comment: Just tried that. I now get this output: [http://en.textsave.org/5jtb](http://en.textsave.org/5jtb)