# python C-extension setup failed with "unable to find vscvarsall.bat" on windows-7

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

On my windows-7, when I wanted to build a C-extension using "distutils", it failed with "unable to find vscvarsall.bat". A little bit web search told me that I may need Visual Studio 2008. I confirmed that indeed, my python2.7 was compiled by Visual Studio 2008 (MSC v. 1500). Now I have 2 questions:

1. Do I really need to install VS 2008 to get my C-extension built by "distutils"?
2. If this is true, since VS is an expensive commercial package, does this limit python application development? Why has python-windows not been compiled by free compiler, eg MINGW?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215734/where-can-a-visual-studio-express-2008-installer-be-found/15215876#15215876

Comment: See [Building lxml for Python 2.7 on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3047542/95735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a C-extension you will need to compile all C Extensions to be used by your python installation **using the same version of the C compiler used to build the python executable from the source**. Hence, the answer to your first question is **yes** - you will need VS 2008 to build the C-extension.

About the second query - please refer [here](http://www.secker.nl/2012/03/08/setup-python-2-7-2-and-mingw-on-windows-xp/) to understand how to setup MinGW with Python 2.7.2. This example uses Windows XP, however I guess it should work on Win 7 as well provided the correct paths have been provided.

Hope this helps