# Python installation error: NumPy package

Tags: python

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://newcoder.io/dataviz/part-0/) and getting an error when I do the following:

```
(DataVizProject) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It gives me a big error log, the last few lines of which are :

```
C:\python\new-coder\dataviz\DataVizProj\build\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.
py:1422: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\python\new-coder
\dataviz\DataVizProj\build\numpy
```

I know it doesn't work because when I do the following steps:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
>>>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you read the error message? "Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.". Install Lapack and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Your other issue (`unable to find vcvarsall.bat`) has also been addressed before on this site, many times. Depending on the exact root cause, you may be able to find help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047542), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551724)...

Answer (score 5):

@Hasnain, when you are using python in windows, eventually you will see this error for some packages.

You have three options when it happen (in order of relevance):

1 - Try to download a MSI file. It will install the library without any problems. To numpy specifically you can download here (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

2 - You can download the whole file and try a python setup.py install and modify the packacge if it raise some errors.

3 - You can compile your own library for your operational system.

Many MSI files you can find here (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 2):

The method recommended in that tutorial works well for Unix systems. If you are on Windows you will go through a lot of trouble trying to build numpy from sources with pip. I will save you some time, follow the official recomendation and try some binary install of the recommended ones in the [official Scipy website](http://scipy.org/install.html). I personally recommend you the Anaconda or the Enthought distribution.

Comment: This is my go to for Windows binary builds, it's a godsend: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

Usually when installing packages on windows, by default python searches for Visual Studio 2008 . You can either install it or use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) Compiler.

If you decide to use MinGW you should edit your *distutils.cfg* file in *Python27\Lib\distutils* directory :

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler = mingw32
```

Comment: I do not have a distutils.cfg file in my C:\Python27\Lib\distutils folder?