# I got the following error when I attempted to install NumPy using pip, anyone know where is the bug?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

My code is entered as follows

```
pip install numpy
```

And I got a chunk of error message as follows. (FYI, pip itself is working fine I suppose since I can install other packages like virtualenv, algopy using pip without getting any error)

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.10.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    Complete output from command c:\python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DONGMI~1\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-u1zl32na\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().re
place('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-q2e5ifr4-record\insta
ll-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DONGMI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-b
uild-u1zl32na\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __f
ile__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-q2e5ifr4-record\install-record.txt --single-v
ersion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DONGMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1zl32na
\numpy
```

Comment: One of the lines says `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. You might want to take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat or this one (specifically for numpy on windows): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730486/python-installation-error-numpy-package

Comment: Download the numpy wheel with intel MKL for your own needs [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and install the .whl file with pip (just replace `numpy` with the file name in your first command)

Comment: @Neitsa@percusse Thanks you both, it worked (I guess the problem is just vcvarsall.bat). Just wonder if http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is constantly updating their packages. Also, is .whl file something like source file and what's the difference between .whl file and the file on Python website after all? Am I supposed to completely depend on this website to download everything I need without bothering Python website in the future?

Comment: A whl file is a file in the [wheel format](http://pythonwheels.com/). It allows the installation of a C extension without a compiler (because the compiled module ships in the whl file). It's easier on Windows where you don't necessarily have the right compiler. No you don't need to use that site for each package, but you'll probably need it if the packages requires a C extension though...