# Porting compiled code (distutils) from Windows 7 to Windows Server

Tags: python, c, windows, compiler-construction, windows-server-2008-r2

I installed a Python package (such as SQLAlchemy), and it compiled C into binaries on a Windows 7 machine. Can I expect to be able to reuse the compiled binaries on Windows Server 2008-R2?

**Edit:** Both are AMD64 Python 2.7.3 and Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there are other issues you need to watch-out for.

Are both systems either 32-bit or 64-bit?  Not just the hardware, but the Python version as well.

Are both systems running the same version of Python?  That's tied to both major and minor version numbers (see `sys.version_info`).

**Edit:**

Your edit has answered these questions, so you should be fine.  Make sure you keep any Python upgrades and modules in step, and only use the 64-bit versions.

Comment: In addition to the above, C extensions have to be compiled using the same version of C runtime library that was used to build Python itself - see [Building lxml for Python 2.7 on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3047542/95735) for details.